# displaying images from mongodb gridfs using spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am new to this area, I have added a number of images to gridfs. Now i want to display all these images on html page. I have retrieved the images from mongodb using the following code.

```
Query query = new Query(where("filename").is("file"));
List<GridFSDBFile> images = gridFsTemplate.find(query);
model.addAttribute("images",images");
```

It gives me all the images, now i have no idea how to display these images on html page. i am using velocity template.

```
 #foreach($image in $images)
    //code for image
 #end
```

Answer (score 3):

Outputting GridFSDBFile type of objects in velocity template does not make sense. You should rather output the URL to the iamge, like

```
#foreach($imageId in $imageIds) 
<img src="getImageFromGridFs?id=$imageId">
#end
```

and then create a getImageFromGridFs Servlet (or relevant Server Side code) to fetch the corresponding image and stream it to the Servlet's OutputStream.

After fetching the image from GridFs, You can access the image data in the Servlet using `GridFSDBFile.getInputStream()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good. Glad to see someone advocating this approach. It is much preferred over stuffing base64 data into an img.src